# How to mix dynamic and constant array in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

How can I mix a constant array of values to a dynamic array in Excel, I am looking through a non-VBA method to do so.  Let me explain the scenario-

Say, I have a column of 7 values.  I can generate an array of same number of values if I want to test a condition for each of these.  Now I want to multiply (sumproduct) the resulting array with another column having actually n+1 values (8 in this case) and I know that last value to be added to this dynamic array is constant say, `FALSE` (`0`).

[image]

In the above example I actually want to add one constant 0/False at the end of dynamic array ($A1:$A7<5), without adding a dummy/hidden row/cell/column?  Can I do it?

I have tried these variations but none of these work

```
=SUMPRODUCT({($A$1:$A$7<5);0}*(E1:E8))

=SUMPRODUCT({($A$1:$A$7<5),0}*(E1:E8))

{=SUMPRODUCT({($A$1:$A$7<5);0}*(E1:E8))} # array formula
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way of actually adding extra elements to an existing array in Excel (as you can in Google Sheets), but you can work round it by testing whether the current row is less than or equal to the number of rows in column A, and taking a default value if not.

In Microsoft 365:

```
=SUM(IF(ROW(E1:E8)<=ROWS(A1:A7),A1:A7<5)*E1:E8)
```

In Excel 2019, the same formula but it has to be array-entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The false default value in the above formula comes from the fact that there is only one argument in the If statement, so if the number of rows is greater than 7, it gives False by default. You could change this, e.g. to 1, by putting in the second argument e.g.

```
=SUM(IF(ROW(E1:E8)<=ROWS(A1:A7),A1:A7<5,1)*E1:E8)
```

A more dynamic version would be

```
=SUM(IF(ROW(E1:INDEX(E:E,COUNT(E:E)))<=ROWS(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A))),A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A))<5)*E1:INDEX(E:E,COUNT(E:E)))
```

which again has to be array-entered if you aren't using Microsoft 365.

In Microsoft 365, you could shorten this considerably using Let():

```
=LET(A,A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)),E,E1:INDEX(E:E,COUNT(E:E)),SUM(IF(ROW(E)<=ROWS(A),A<5)*E))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort! but it is not working in my case? evaluating to 0 only

Comment: convert booleans with --(A1:A7<5)

Comment: Can you please explain where have added constant value to this array?

Comment: Sorry, I had to fire up my old desktop to test it in Excel 2019. Looks like it has to be array-entered - will add to my answer.

Comment: So as mentioned in my answer I'm not actually adding elements to the first array, but I can get round it by testing whether we have run off the end of the array, in which case the formula will use the default value, False.

Comment: I suppose you could make this more general by testing which of the two arrays is longer (rather than assuming that it is always the second one) - maybe that is a separate question.

Comment: But my question is bit different? I actually want to modify my first result array from {1, 1,1,1,0,0,0} to {1, 1,1,1,0,0,0,0} or {1, 1,1,1,0,0,0,1}  as the case may be

Comment: The question seemed to indicate that the added element was always going to be a constant (false) and I think I've provided a reasonable answer to that. Probably spent enough time on it now.

Comment: I feel sorry for your time, but I am still unable to understand how have you added any constant value to the dynamic array generated by testing the condition in first column of seven values?

Comment: Effectively I have made a copy of the array where the last element is set to False. That may be the closest that you will get, although others may have alternative suggestions.

Comment: Thanks I will try and tell you.

Comment: Perhaps I should have pointed out that you can put any value you like in the IF statement e.g. =SUM(IF(ROW(E1:E8)<=ROWS(A1:A7),A1:A7<5,1)*E1:E8) will give a default value of 1 instead of False :-)

Comment: working fine! many thanks.  Accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 1):

In O365 with Sequence you can spin up something like:

```
 =LET(arr, $E$1:$E$8, bools, --($A$1:$A$7>6), boolRows, SEQUENCE(ROWS(bools)), endArr, XLOOKUP( SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)), boolRows, bools, "DEFAULT VALUE",1,2),  SUMPRODUCT(arr,endArr))
```

So in place of "DEFAULT VALUE", you can test with 1, 0, 10, and see if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using O365, so I cannot test it.  Upvoted for the effort.  Thanks